# Unable to Group on MSAccess SQL multiple search query

Tags: sql, ms-access

please can you help me before I go out of my mind. I've spent a while on this now and resorted to asking you helpful wonderful people. I have a search query:

```
SELECT  Groups.GroupID, 
        Groups.GroupName, 
        (   SELECT  Sum(SiteRates.SiteMonthlySalesValue) 
            FROM    SiteRates 
            WHERE   InvoiceSites.SiteID = SiteRates.SiteID
        ) AS SumOfSiteRates, 
        (   SELECT  Count(InvoiceSites.SiteID) 
            FROM    InvoiceSites 
            WHERE   SiteRates.SiteID = InvoiceSites.SiteID
        ) AS CountOfSites
FROM    (InvoiceSites 
        INNER JOIN (Groups 
            INNER JOIN SitesAndGroups 
                ON Groups.GroupID = SitesAndGroups.GroupID
        ) ON InvoiceSites.SiteID = SitesAndGroups.SiteID) 
        INNER JOIN SiteRates 
            ON InvoiceSites.SiteID = SiteRates.SiteID
GROUP BY Groups.GroupID
```

With the following table relationship

[image]
http://m-ls.co.uk/ExtFiles/SQL-Relationship.jpg

Without the GROUP BY entry I can get a list of the entries I want but it drills the results down by SiteID where instead I want to GROUP BY the GroupID. I know this is possible but lack the expertise to complete this.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do is add `groups.Name` to the `GROUP BY` clause, however I would adopt for a slightly different approach and try to avoid the subqueries if possible. Since you have already joined to all the required tables you can just use normal aggregate functions:

```
SELECT  Groups.GroupID, 
        Groups.GroupName, 
        SUM(SiteRates.SiteMonthlySalesValue) AS SumOfSiteRates, 
        COUNT(InvoiceSites.SiteID) AS CountOfSites
FROM    (InvoiceSites 
        INNER JOIN (Groups 
            INNER JOIN SitesAndGroups 
                ON Groups.GroupID = SitesAndGroups.GroupID
        )   ON InvoiceSites.SiteID = SitesAndGroups.SiteID) 
        INNER JOIN SiteRates 
            ON InvoiceSites.SiteID = SiteRates.SiteID
GROUP BY Groups.GroupID, Groups.GroupName;
```

Comment: This worked for me (apart from I took out the first GROUP BY statement and just used the second GROUP BY statement). Thanks so much for your help - I really appreciate it :D

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo. I have removed that now.

Comment: Thanks again you little legend

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like the following:

```
SELECT Groups.GroupID, Groups.GroupName, SumResults.SiteID, SumResults.SumOfSiteRates, SumResults.CountOfSites
FROM Groups INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT SitesAndGroups.SiteID, Sum(SiteRates.SiteMonthlySalesValue) AS SumOfSiteRates, Count(InvoiceSites.SiteID) AS CountOfSites
FROM SitesAndGroups INNER JOIN (InvoiceSites INNER JOIN SiteRates ON InvoiceSites.SiteID = SiteRates.SiteID) ON SitesAndGroups.SiteID = InvoiceSites.SiteID
GROUP BY SitesAndGroups.SiteID
) AS SumResults ON Groups.SiteID = SumResults.SiteID
```

This query will group your information based on the SiteID like you want.  That query is referenced in the from statement linking to the Groups table to pull the group information that you want.

Comment: I tried this but I was thrown up an Enter Parameter Value for Groups.SiteID on the final line. I know that there wasn't a Groups.SiteID so I tried to spend some time reverse engineering your statement but failed to work out what should have been used instead